# .NET CLI (dotnet build) and AOP libraries

Tags: asp.net-core, postsharp, .net-core, dotnet-cli

Is it possible to get any AOP libraries running with the new .NET CLI; i.e. `dotnet build`?

Most notably, I am looking for ways to do method interception.

I am NOT looking for .NET Core compatibility. I am still using the normal .NET Framework.

Comment: Isn't requesting for libraries off-topic on SO?

Comment: This is not supported by PostSharp yet, but it is planned in PostSharp 5.1 (https://www.postsharp.net/support/roadmap).

Answer (score 1):

AOP is either with a post compiler such as postsharp or with cut points within an ioc container. As for core nothing yet but I would image one will pop up soon.